How to test a method that calls a persistence method returning IQueryable
I read in a few places that it's a good practice for a method that calls the database to return IQueryable because it allows extending queries in services using methods like Select, Where, etc., and prevents loading unfiltered data into memory.
However, I'm encountering an issue when testing a method that uses this approach. I get the following error:

The source IQueryable doesn’t implement IAsyncEnumerable. Only sources that implement IAsyncEnumerable can be used for Entity Framework asynchronous operations.

How can I handle this method in my test, or should I approach it in a different way?
Here is the GenerateCustomerReportAsync method:
public async Task GenerateCustomerReportAsync()
{
    var jurisdictions = await _customerPersistenceService.GetAll()
        .Select(j => new { j.Name, j.SurName }).ToListAsync();
}

And the method in the persistence service:
public interface ICustomerPersistenceService
{
    IQueryable<Customers> GetAll();
}

public IQueryable<Customers> GetAll()
{
    return _clientContext.Customers.AsQueryable();
}

Here is the mock code from the test:
var customers = new List<Customer>
{
    new Customer { /* initialize customer properties */ }
}.AsQueryable();

subCustomerPersistenceService = Substitute.For<ICustomerPersistenceService>();
subCustomerPersistenceService.GetAll().Returns(customers);

I tried to use .AsQueryable() for a list in my test. I expected it to simulate the behavior of an IQueryable collection returned from the database, allowing my method to execute without errors. I am considering using an Expression to send the selector and then return a List, but I'm not sure if this is the best approach, or if I should just use IEnumerable and AsEnumerable().

Almost in all cases returning a IQueryable directly is bad practise. Keep your dbcontext separated from all other layers.

en how can I avoid loading a huge amount of data into memory? Should I set expression parameters for WHERE and SELECT to create dynamic queries in the persistence layer, or should I create separate methods for each purpose? I don't get your point. The DbContext is separated, and I return only IQueryable. From what I understand, it's just a query that can be modified.

Expose a methods that will return exactly what you need. If your have like ten different cases then expose ten different methods that will cover all those cases. Exposing IQueryable should be avoided at all cost. If you do that then other layers in your app gain access to your database entities and they should not be aware of them. Why? Because for example in application layer you should think in terms of business logic not in terms of database logic. That makes it much simpler for you. Unless we are talking about some console app without layers then just do whatever suits you best.

I have a 4-layer architecture: controllers > mapping service > business logic service > database access service. I'm concerned about performance when retrieving large numbers of records. IEnumerable loads everything into memory before filtering, which seems inefficient. Some articles recommend IEnumerable, others IQueryable. I'm confused about which is better for performance.Maybe that's comrpomise send query expression for where and select and return list ? Like in this article https://ardalis.com/avoid-dbcontext-iqueryable-proliferation/

It works until you want to perform an async operation against the IQueryable.  For instance if you method under test looks something like:
public async Task<IEnumerable<CustomerViewModel>> GetRecentCustomers(int pageNumber, int pageSize)
{
    var cutoffDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-7);
    var customers = await _customerService.GetAll()
        .Where(c => c.Orders.Any(o => o.OrderDate >= cutoffDate)
        .ProjectTo<CustomerViewModel>(_config)
        .Skip(pageNumber * pageSize)
        .Take(pageSize)
        .ToListAsync();
    return customers;
}

... having a mock return an IQueryable of a regular List<T> doesn't work as the underlying List<T> doesn't support async operations . Fortunately there is an implementation for mocking a List<T> as something that will work through asynchronous calls, MockQueryable. (https://www.nuget.org/packages/MockQueryable.Core) Then the only change is instead of:
var customers = new List<Customer>
{
    new Customer { /* initialize customer properties */ }
}.AsQueryable();

... you use:
var customers = new List<Customer>
{ 
    new Customer { /* initialize customer properties */ }
}.BuildMock(); // Returns your IQueryable<Customer>

I recommend using the BuildMock for all mocked IQueryables so that your tests will continue to work if you re-factor code from synchronous to asynchronous without breaking an existing test.

Thanks for the great answer! With this NuGet package, it works perfectly. Do you know how I can achieve this without using the NuGet package? Is it possible to handle this by using an in-memory database?

@capslo Using in-memory database is strongly discouraged by EF themselves. Personally, I wouldn't use mocks either. LINQ-to-objects behaves fundamentally different than LINQ to an IQueryable SQL backend.

Good to know your point of view. What do you recommend?

I prefer integration tests against the same database vendor as in production. Unit tests can be used when either the queries are really simple or when they (the queries) only serve as sources for test doubles in pure business-logic tests.

Yes, unit tests can test behaviour outside of the data where the mocked service/repository returns an expected set of data (or not) depending on what you want to test. To cover more end-to-end behaviour, use an integration database with a real DB since in-memory databases do not behave like real ones in terms of indexing, constraints, etc.  Unit tests focus on code logic based on data and the like and should be run often, so as fast as possible. Integration tests can be run periodically like prior to release candidate builds.
